# How to set custom zoom in Chrome developer tools Device Toolbar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have custom screen sizes set up in my Chrome dev tools, but the zoom levels for how big the screen appears are limited to: 50%, 75%, 100%, 125%, 150%, Fit to window

[image]

Is there a way to add custom zoom levels or zooming to an arbitrary level?

Answer (score 1):

You can make visible ruler at top right corner menu button, and to start to zoom by clicking at ruler values. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pJ8y.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dimension "responsive" and then define as you wish.